# How to pass a reference to open serial port in C++?

Tags: c++, serial-port

I need to pass a reference to open serial port to a function in C++. Right now I'm opening and closing serial port inside a function, which is of course a bad and inefficient way:

```
int main()
{
    myFunc();
}
```

myFunc is defined in a separate library:

```
int myFunc(void)
{
   Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM6");              
   if (!SP->IsConnected()) {
       cout << "Arduino is  not connected" << endl;
       return -1;
   }
   // do something
   SP->~Serial();
}
```

If I try to open the port in main and pass a reference to SP to the function it gives me an error:

```
int main()
{
    Serial* SP = new Serial("\\\\.\\COM6");                 
    if (!SP->IsConnected()) {
       cout << "Device is  not connected" << endl;
       return -1;
    }
    myFunc(SP);
    SP->~Serial();
}

int myFunc(Serial* SP)
{
   // do something
}
```

I tried different variants of function definition like 
    int myFunc(Serial *SP)
or
    int myFunc(Serial SP)
but noting works. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: First of all: A pointer is not the same as a reference! Regarding your problem: You simply pass it to your function: `myFunc(SP);` when calling it, and that's it.

Comment: Sorry, I just mistyped and forgot to pass the argument, but I had it in my original code and it's not what the problem is.

Comment: Well, how are we supposed to know.? Take care and double read your question before clicking the [post] button please. Also tell us what exactly _isn't working_ when you do so. Otherwise your question is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems:

- you are not passing any argument to myFunc
- you call explicitly destructor but do not free memory
- you create objects on the heap without need to do so.

Below I tried to fix some problems in your code:

```
int myFunc(Serial& SP)
{
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    Serial SP("\\\\.\\COM6");                 
    if (!SP.IsConnected()) {
       cout << "Device is  not connected" << endl;
       return -1;
    }
    myFunc(SP);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to pass the argument. But with your code it still does not work, I'm getting the compiler error " 'Serial': undeclared identifier" pointing to my mylib.h. Here is my code now

Comment: int main()
{
    Serial SP("\\\\.\\COM6");                 
    if (!SP.IsConnected()) {
       cout << "Device is  not connected" << endl;
       return -1;
    }
    myFunc(SP);
}

Comment: @evi: You need to `#include` the library header file before the forward declaration of `myFunc`.  Don't be afraid to put `#include` lines into your own header files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated complete code and it now works. I also needed #include "SerialClass.h" in the .h file. Thanks a lot to everyone who helped!

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include "SerialClass.h"

int main()
{
    Serial SP("\\\\.\\COM6");                 
    if (!SP.IsConnected()) {
       cout << "Device is  not connected" << endl;
       return -1;
    }
    myFunc(SP);
    return 1;
}
```

in mylib.cpp

```
#include "SerialClass.h"

int myFunc(Serial& SP)
{
    // do something
    SP.WriteData(6, 1);
    return 1;
}
```

in mylib.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _MYLIB_H_
#define _MYLIB_H_
#include "SerialClass.h"   

int myFunc(Serial& SP);

#endif
```